# SQL output error when try to find duplicate value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, duplicates, unique-key

```
select

count([Item Nbr]) as [Item Nbr],

count([Item Flags]) as [Item Flags],

count(UPC) as UPC,

count([Store Nbr]) as [Store Nbr] ,

count (RetrievalWeek) as RetrievalWeek,

* from tblStoreItemForecast

GROUP BY

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,

[Store Nbr], [Week 01 Forecast], [Week 02 Forecast],

[Week 03 Forecast],[Week 04 Forecast],[Week 05 Forecast],

[Week 06 Forecast],[Week 07 Forecast],[Week 08 Forecast],[Week 09 Forecast],

[Week 10 Forecast],[Week 11 Forecast],[Week 12 Forecast],[Week 13 Forecast],

[Week 14 Forecast],[Week 15 Forecast],RetrievalWeek

having (count(*) > 1)

order by RetrievalWeek desc
```

I got the message error Msg 8120,

> Level 16, State 1, Line 76
>
> Column 'tblStoreItemForecast.Week 16 Forecast' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 91
>
> Ambiguous column name 'RetrievalWeek'.

Can anyone help me why this happen.

I tried another method

if i run the below code it gives me no result as i am using record no (unique key) here

```
select

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,[Store Nbr],RetrievalWeek,recordno,COUNT(*)

from tblStoreItemForecast

GROUP BY

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,[Store Nbr],

RetrievalWeek,recordno

having

count(*) > 1

order by RetrievalWeek desc
```

but if I run the below code without using record no as it is unique here it
gives result

```
select

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,[Store Nbr],RetrievalWeek,COUNT(*)

from tblStoreItemForecast

GROUP BY

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,[Store Nbr],

RetrievalWeek

having

count(*) > 1

order by RetrievalWeek desc
```

i want to count the duplicate by using record no how to write the can not figure out i also use inner join but getting error space in the log can not be reused. Is there any solution?

Comment: This looks like sql server, not mysql which you tagged. The error is also pretty clear, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question to retag appropriately.

Comment: Remove the * in your SELECT

Comment: @nacho but i need the other remaining columns also

Comment: Why are you aggregating and grouping on the same columns.

Comment: @larnu i want to count duplicate column by using all column name without using count(*) where i can found all column and the duplicate record and count the duplicate recod also

Comment: Why not use a windowed count then? Aggregating and grouping on the same columns is always the sign of a flaw.

Comment: @larnu sorry i have no knowledge about the windowed count can you elaborate it kindly

Comment: To be honest it looks like you have a bit of a design flaw here. You have violated 1NF by using repeating groups. [Week 01 Forecast] etc. You have also made it more difficult on yourself by putting spaces in your column names. The grouping by every column sort of suggest your table is also lacking a primary key.

Comment: @SeanLange can you help me to get the answer as i tried another inner join step but getting result or getting error , actually for duplicate also there is recordno column which is unique for duplicate record also , so how to write the query for this case using unique recordno , so that i can identify the duplicates and delete them

Comment: There really isn't much anybody can do to help without table structures and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You have an output column alias with the same name as a table column. Try adding an underscore to differentiate as below.

```
select

count([Item Nbr]) as [Item Nbr],

count([Item Flags]) as [Item Flags],

count(UPC) as UPC,

count([Store Nbr]) as [Store Nbr] ,

count (RetrievalWeek) as Retrieval_Week,

* from tblStoreItemForecast

GROUP BY

[Item Nbr],[Item Flags],UPC,

[Store Nbr], [Week 01 Forecast], [Week 02 Forecast],

[Week 03 Forecast],[Week 04 Forecast],[Week 05 Forecast],

[Week 06 Forecast],[Week 07 Forecast],[Week 08 Forecast],[Week 09 Forecast],

[Week 10 Forecast],[Week 11 Forecast],[Week 12 Forecast],[Week 13 Forecast],

[Week 14 Forecast],[Week 15 Forecast],RetrievalWeek

having (count(*) > 1)

order by RetrievalWeek desc
```